# d3 Doesn't Render Some text

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the below code to generate a scatter diagram with a text label beside each point. The data is a length 35 array and it generates 35 circles. The problem is that the text only renders indexes 34 -- 17 and just stops (I have the axis set up "backwards" with smaller values going up and to the right). Testing shows that the .data method just stops at index 16 with no errors or output to the console. I am stumped so any help would be much appreciated:

```
       svg.selectAll('circle')
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append('circle')
       .attr('class', d => {return d.Doping == "" ? "circle-green" : "circle-
      red"})
      .attr('cx', (d, i) => xScale(d.SecondsBehind))
      .attr('cy', d => yScale(d.Place))
      .attr('r', 5);

     svg.selectAll('text')
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append('text')
       .text((d, i) => d.Name)
       .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale(d.SecondsBehind) + 20)
       .attr('y', d => yScale(d.Place) - 3);
```

Comment: I bet $500 that you already have text elements in that SVG (probably the ticks). Thus, instead of `svg.selectAll('text')`, do `svg.selectAll('d3isAwesome')`. Please, write literally "d3isAwesome".

Comment: You should really provide a working demo, now! Seriously, it might well be worth 500 bucks, although I'm afraid @GerardoFurtado is right assuming there are already texts in your SVG. If he is not, we will take him at his word, though!

Comment: @altocumulus Should I have said 500 RP instead? They are also green... (wait a minute, is that they way StackExchange sites psychologically hooks us? Making the RP colour similar to money?)

Comment: Looks like I owe Gerardo some $$$. svg.selectAll('d3isAwesome') works awesomely.

Comment: Thanks much -- I would have never thought of that

Comment: You should really use `svg.selectAll(null)` instead, which will have the same effect but is much faster. For an explanation you might want to sift through my discussion in the comments to @GerardoFurtado 's answer to  [*"How do your write a function that returns values from an array?"*](/q/44232920).

Comment: Thanks for the svg.selectAll(null) suggestion. Works great and is much clearer.  This D3 stuff is fun when I get it to work :)